# how to let docker use only external space

Tags: docker, nvidia-jetson

I'm using Nvidia Jetson board having very small storage.

During using docker, It always give me an error like `no space left on device`

I'm trying to use external usb stick and let docker use only space on it.

So I found out someways to overcome, but it failed.

1. move `/var/lib/docker` into usb stick and make symbolic link to previous path
2. move `/var/run/docker` also like above

but It seems that docker still use device space, because I encountered the error again like.

`failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /usr/share/perl/5.26.1/unicore/To/NFKCCF.pl: no space left on device`

Is there any clear way to force docker to only use external space?